# Magento scanner error can't reach base URL

Tags: security-scan-tool

A couple of days ago I started to get this error..

Security Tool was unable to reach the base URL.

Any ideas? No changes have been made
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing this for a few days too.

We use a geoip redirector to select the right 'store' for an incoming IP address country.  I believe this is interfering with the magento site scanner.

I guess it is a recently introduced bug either in the plugin or the scanner.

To debug it I re-scheduled the scan and used our monitoring tools to find the IP address of the scanner.  I then added this to our geoip plugin 'skip redirect for this IP' list.

The scan then proceeded OK.

I'm not sure how 'static' the scan IP address is, so I anticipate needing to regularly update the 'skip redirect' list until either the plugin is fixed or the security scanner is fixed.

The redirector plugin I am using is BSS Commerce Version 1.3.9 Magento 2 GeoIP Store Switcher.  I see there is an update from November - but we've been running without that for some time... v1.4.0 (Nov 11, 2021): Fix bug can not close popup.